# Remove "api" prefix in .NET Core Routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

All routes in .NET Core are starting with /api for example:

```
/api/store
```

Which I want to be just:

```
/store
```

In older verions of the framework I could edit this in the web.config...does anyone know where that configuration lives now?

Comment: It was never in the web.config, it's in the routing config. It's not hard to find....

Comment: depends on how you set up routing.  It could be an attribute on the controller itself, or it could be in the `Startup` area, where routes can be registered

Comment: I'd rather have it in the controller

Comment: You get to put it where ever you want :)

Comment: wow i didnt see the route tag with "api"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute `[Route("/store/{youraction}")]` or create new `MapRoute` in `Startup.cs` (`Configure` section)